# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'void | ISomeModel'

Tags: typescript

Here is my Interface `ISomeModel`

```
export interface ISomeModel {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  // .... other fields
}
```

Here is my class SomeService

```
class SomeService {
  static fromJsonAndId(json: any, id?: string): ISomeModel {
    return {
      id: id,
      title: json.title,
      description: json.description,
      // ..... other fields
    } as ISomeModel;
  }

  handleFirestoreError(error: any) {
    if (error.code === 'permission-denied' || error.code === 'unauthenticated') {
      tokenService.logout(true);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  create(someModel: ISomeModel): Promise<ISomeModel | void> {
    return db
      .add(someModel)
      .then((doc) => SomeService.fromJsonAndId(someModel, doc.id))
      .catch((err) => this.handleFirestoreError(err));
  }

}

export default new SomeService();
```

Here is my react component where I am using the create method:

```
const someInstance = await someService.create(someModelObj);
console.log('created', someInstance.id);
```

But I get this error in my ide(webstorm):

[image]
The `create` function would either return `ISomeModel` instance or throw error. It can never return void. So why am I getting that error? And how do I fix it?

Comment: What does `tokenService.logout(true)` do?

Comment: The function `handleFirestoreError` path of `tokenService.logout` returns `undefined` or throws.

Comment: `tokenService.logout` returns void.

Answer (score 1):

```
const someInstance = await someService.create(someModelObj) as ISomeModel
```

or maybe you can use a typeof to detect is a void or a ISomeModel

Comment: I think this is a short and smart way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can explicitly tell TypeScript that when an error is being handled, you return a `null` value. So you can either have an object with type definition of `ISomeModel` or a `null` value (Here you can use **optional chaining operator - ?** to make sure you're only accessing the object if it exists). The code will look like below (I have mocked some objects like `db` and `tokenService`) :-

```js
export interface ISomeModel {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  // .... other fields
}

type Nullable<T> = T | null;

const db = {
    add:(someModel:ISomeModel)=>Promise.resolve({id:'sd',title:'df',description:'fdf'})
}

const tokenService = {
    logout:(someboolean:boolean)=>{}
}

class SomeService {
  static fromJsonAndId(json: any, id?: string): ISomeModel {
    return {
      id: id,
      title: json.title,
      description: json.description,
      // ..... other fields
    } as ISomeModel;
  }

  handleFirestoreError(error: any) {
    if (error.code === 'permission-denied' || error.code === 'unauthenticated') {
        tokenService.logout(true);
        return null;
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  create(someModel: ISomeModel): Promise<Nullable<ISomeModel>> {
    return db
      .add(someModel)
      .then((doc:any) => SomeService.fromJsonAndId(someModel, doc.id))
      .catch((err:any) => this.handleFirestoreError(err));
  }

}

export default new SomeService();

const someService = new SomeService();
try{
const someInstance = await someService.create({  id: '3434343',
  title: 'Some object title',
  description: 'some object description'});
console.log('created', someInstance?.id);
}
catch(err:any){
    // handle other errors
}
```

Also [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICSAylALYgCyUAJiADYIDewCyNA-AFwIDOcMVAHMA3KwRwkceiB79BKUeLq9cgiJKgo5A4WLYB6AwgB0ZkwihwAFhgSYkDGr2ABfYMDgBPCAQByAK709NgARjIAPAAqAHwIALwIUQgAPggoQfRiwLha-Ag0oQnM4mzYNDRcABS85FS0DFwkddR09ACU8TEACjDkSLwgJjAgtfQAbiBVTEiVAOS8NHMANJLSsnM0mCsqakgaSFpcc5hbc67tbh65KPlwUADWICjEGONI+MUsbGz0UEJQAJwaq1CihKBQGTYbTgyEgaGdGJMdzuHIhXi8BCkCivGDvT7fPhwbCSXD2PpkABStRQAEEUDRCDQqgArGk8aFeZbsbhEhRCdo8ZoUVoMEo-BAjOABGAocUS9g8WbLUo-NYyHhsrQmdUgFUKgqjPYHI4ILUoEy7dSaFD6hVGUzmCxWWwweyOejOVWuBDYTHC+ptfQIVFsazQmgyABiSBG-FgIAAojA+jAqhhUxyUF52vK2EhMAh0ynYCZcnQEvFEnNfDAyANeIcUABaOgoRxLVJpDOl8sEKvVgIobBA2xoD4kkBLXOEg33J4vN4fIZ-AFAqoCAIgdrBg1SmVyjLBXchhAMQZ5tXWPoAdzPJZgJ-cbFDCDU8PQNRaDXoQuxgYYQUEF6fpBgiQJgjCSIA1FegYjiWdJRAaVZQKUJVTYExymZUEAI6DDTBsZ4qiqGgoFwLhOVzLosTqXF8SGTAKWpLR6UZHDvzabkyNwExZnaS4DTLElcGsEiM0o7NqLiGwBhMcMGWjWNRnuEZk1TYsYAE4NUVRcBoHgQ0cCCRAUBAO9-3o5cqh3a48kQXCrM+RIzIsuil3wGyxAELwWBufJcMIW5iRQZzfRvbApD4dy8WXMsRknaZ80qBA5gAZgAFky7KVnEXUeDmf9LFCFkQFwRBdVytgrX2G0Ctw4rSvKw1VGtJtzls-y4RMVcqjmd9JyWblAuC6F8A4PiaFs9xcBEsSJKoxCHQUyMCBdOwexgFxXCAA) is the typescript playground

Comment: This looks like the correct way to do it, though slightly verbose. I feel scenarios like mine should have been handled in ts itself automatically. Anyways thanks for the answer!